# Ionic 2 / Angular 2: How to emit click event from a hyperlink or button on a Ionic 2 Alert?

Tags: angular, hyperlink, ionic2

My Home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }


  ShowAlert(){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: '<b>Information</b>',
        subTitle: `<a href="#" (click)="launchUrl('https://www.google.com')">Open Google</a>`,
        buttons: ['Close']
      });

    alert.present();
  }

  launchUrl(url){
    console.log(url);
  }
}
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
<button  ion-button icon-only color="light" style="float: right" (click)="ShowAlert()">
Show Alert
</button>
```

And I do get the Alert triggered successfully.

Now when I click the hyperlink: `Open Google`, nothing happens. I want to call the `launchUrl()` function on click of the hyperlink.

```
  launchUrl(url){
    console.log(url);
  }
```

Once I am able to call launchUrl(), then later I hope to modify it as shown below to call the InAppBrowser using cordova plugin.

```
launchUrl(url){
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true");
        });
    }
```

But right now I am not even able to call the basic `launchUrl()` function. 
I tried both `(click)="launchUrl('https://www.google.com')"` and  `(click)="this.launchUrl('https://www.google.com')"`, but no success.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML for the alert gets removed by [Angular2 Sanitiser](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html). You should add it to the 'trusted list' using the `bypassSecurityTrust` functions if you want to stay.

But that is not going to fix your problem, because you have assumed Angular2 binding will occur on the Alert's subtitle. The Alert is not designed for the way you are trying to use it.

refer to the [AlertController's documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/) and you can see how to use a Button and Handler to do so.

You probably need to change your design a bit to be able to use Alert out of the box. for example use this

```
  ShowAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Information',
    message: 'Search Google?',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('start going to google...');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I could not find anything in Ionic 2's Alert documentation. I will search more on event emitters and maybe someone else may have some solution. I think there should be some way of calling functions from Ionic 2's alerts.

Comment: Or I will try to use Ionic 2's Modal. Thanks.

Comment: I added a code showing how Alert could be used to do the job for you. But it won't create same UI design you have above

Comment: Yes, I also did the same. Thanks.